# Shell dd script - Fills zeros instead of skipping bytes

Tags: zero, dd

Ok for those who are interested i finally found the answer:
dd seek=$(($offset)) bs=1 count=$c conv=notrunc if=$loc2 of=$loc1

So i want to copy the "text" of $loc2 and want to paste it in $loc1 at offset 0x2 without deleting the bytes before it. When i run this command no matter at what position it doesn't *skip* the bytes but instead replacing every byte with 00 00 ... until it reached the offset and from there it works normally.
For e.g.:

```
offset=0x2
loc2 = 6E 6F 70 71
loc1 = 7E 3B 11 FF   loc1 should change to this ---> 7E 3B 6E 6F 70 71 but instead changes to: 00 00 6E 6F 70 71
```

### This is my small code

```
offset=0x2
dd skip=$(($offset)) bs=1 count=5 conv=notrunc < $loc2 > $loc1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using redirection so what actually happens is that `$loc1` gets truncated. You could try specifying `if=$loc2` and `of=$loc1` for `dd`.

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what i want to achieve. I want everything from $loc2 to $loc1. Thanks for the heads up though!